# Subscription Model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking to design a notification service which on certain conditions when met would send status report to users.I am not able to understand how to save those conditions in database like model wise ( for example user is interested in seeing report where job is 100% or user is interested in report which has failed status).The approach I was thinking was to have either columns for each of those conditions or serialize those conditions and save it as json in db.
Please provide some insights to it?

Comment: FYI I removed asp.net as mentioned on the same question is about MVC asp.net mvc

Comment: Normally questions that relates to opinions are not well received or recommended to be asked on SO

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you could look into a message queue based system where you would put a message on a queue to indicate that you want to send a report to someone. 
A message handler like NServicebus can then monitor the queue and handle the actual sending of reports via email or other means.